# Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode)

Tags: spring-boot, csv, spring-batch

I am getting below error while running a simple batch job which is reading a CSV file and formatting the object and writing the output to a different file .

Both the file already exist in resource folder of Springbok project .
This is an example from book "The Definitive Guide to Spring Batch" .

Need suggestion to solve this .

Build : building the project jar

```
$ mvn clean package
```

Run : running the jar from terminal

```
$ java -jar target/chapter09_format_customer_address-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar customerFile=/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/data.csv outputFile=/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/formattedCustomerFile.txt
```

Error :

```
2022-08-24 17:35:04.323  INFO 9860 --- [           main] hapter09FormatCustomerAddressApplication : Starting Chapter09FormatCustomerAddressApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.11 on PSINGH6-M-KHCS with PID 9860 (/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/target/chapter09_format_customer_address-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by psingh6 in /Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address)
2022-08-24 17:35:04.326  INFO 9860 --- [           main] hapter09FormatCustomerAddressApplication : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2022-08-24 17:35:04.961  INFO 9860 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-08-24 17:35:04.993  INFO 9860 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 12 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-08-24 17:35:05.750  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-24 17:35:05.765  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-24 17:35:05.765  INFO 9860 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-24 17:35:05.915  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-24 17:35:05.915  INFO 9860 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1508 ms
2022-08-24 17:35:06.073  INFO 9860 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-24 17:35:06.396  INFO 9860 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-08-24 17:35:06.611  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-08-24 17:35:06.723  INFO 9860 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-08-24 17:35:06.986  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-08-24 17:35:07.207  INFO 9860 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2022-08-24 17:35:07.818  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-08-24 17:35:07.828  INFO 9860 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-24 17:35:07.994  WARN 9860 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-08-24 17:35:08.255  WARN 9860 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.batch.JpaBatchConfigurer         : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs. To silence this warning, set 'spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create' to 'default'.
2022-08-24 17:35:08.259  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: POSTGRES
2022-08-24 17:35:08.276  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2022-08-24 17:35:08.378  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-24 17:35:08.388  INFO 9860 --- [           main] hapter09FormatCustomerAddressApplication : Started Chapter09FormatCustomerAddressApplication in 4.575 seconds (JVM running for 5.009)
2022-08-24 17:35:08.390  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner   : Running default command line with: [customerFile=/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/data.csv, outputFile=/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/formattedCustomerFile.txt]
2022-08-24 17:35:08.613  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=formatJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{outputFile=/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/formattedCustomerFile.txt, customerFile=/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/data.csv, run.id=11}]
2022-08-24 17:35:08.687  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [formatStep]
2022-08-24 17:35:08.756 ERROR 9860 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step formatStep in job formatJob

org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$243107d1.open(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:104) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:413) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar!/:2.7.3]
        at com.example.chapter09_format_customer_address.Chapter09FormatCustomerAddressApplication.main(Chapter09FormatCustomerAddressApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[chapter09_format_customer_address-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[chapter09_format_customer_address-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[chapter09_format_customer_address-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[chapter09_format_customer_address-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): ServletContext resource [/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/data.csv]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:257) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar!/:4.3.6]
        ... 51 common frames omitted

2022-08-24 17:35:08.872  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [formatStep] executed in 185ms
2022-08-24 17:35:08.920  INFO 9860 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=formatJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{outputFile=/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/formattedCustomerFile.txt, customerFile=/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/data.csv, run.id=11}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 280ms
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>chapter09_format_customer_address</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chapter09_format_customer_address</name>
    <description>chapter09_format_customer_address</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=chapter09_format_customer_address
server.port=8080

# database config
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5555/spring_batch
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# spring batch
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

FormattedTextFileJob.java

```
package com.example.chapter09_format_customer_address;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Configuration
public class FormattedTextFileJob {
    @Inject
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Inject
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> customerFileReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['customerFile']}") Resource inputFile){
        FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader = new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Customer>().name("customerFileReader")
                .resource(inputFile)
                .delimited()
                .names(new String[]{"firstName", "middleInitial", "lastName", "address", "city", "state", "zip"})
                .targetType(Customer.class)
                .build();
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters['outputFile']}") Resource outputFile){
        FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> writer = new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
                .name("customerItemWriter")
                .resource(outputFile)
                .formatted()
                .format("%s %s lives at %s %s in %s, %s.")
                .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName", "address", "city", "state", "zip"})
                .build();
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step formatStep(){
        Step step = this.stepBuilderFactory.get("formatStep")
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(10)
                .reader(customerFileReader(null))
                .writer(customerItemWriter(null))
                .build();
        return step;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job formatJob(){
        Job job = this.jobBuilderFactory.get("formatJob")
                .start(formatStep())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .build();
        return job;
    }
}
```

screenshot :
[image]

Comment: In first place i would trust the error message, and check the existence/content of `/Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/data.csv`

Comment: But if you insist, it is there(?), I would be curious/suspicious about "**ServletContext** resource" ..and (quickly) try `file:///Users/...` (to prepend the `file://` protocol to resource)

Comment: "servlet contex root" is normally that "thing"/folder/collection, which contains "WEB-INF"

Comment: ..and since you have spring-web on board, the interpretation of `/` as a servlet context resource by default (in favor to classpath or file resource) is legal/excusable/makes sense

Comment: Thank you ! Finally it worked by adding file:///Users/... !
`
java -jar target/chapter09_format_customer_address-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar customerFile=file:///Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/data.csv outputFile=file:///Users/psingh6/Documents/learn/springBatch/chapter09_format_customer_address/src/main/resources/formattedCustomerFile.txt
`

Comment: Since it (the input file) is in src/main/resources (it will be (filtered&) packed (by default) into "classpath"), 
 `customerFile=classpath:/data.csv` could work "just fine"! (Regarding "output", I would still recommend "file://")

Answer (score 0):

Create bean file like this and use `org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource` ;

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<CourseCountry> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[fullPathFileName]}") String pathToFile) {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<CourseCountry>()
      .name("studentItemReader")        
      .resource(new PathResource(pathToFile))
      .lineMapper(lineMapper())
      .linesToSkip(1)
      .build();
}
```